Models for $(\infty,1)$-categories
Various models for the theory of $(\infty,1)$-categories have been proposed and a significant amount of work has also been devoted to model independent theory (e.g. Riehl, Verity and others) of $(\infty,1)$-categories or comparing various models (e.g. Bergner). The most developed and most popular model seems to be the model of quasicategories. However, quasicategories (also called $\infty$-categories) seem to require a (relatively) high level of technical skill (with simplicial sets and model categories) to be used effectively.
My list of questions is:

What are the benefits of working with quasicategories (for an algebraic topologist or algebraic geometer)? It seems that this is the only model that people in these and related fields know and use. So what I mean is: is this only for sociological reasons (like the fact that quasicategories are so much more developed) or something else?
Let us assume familiarity with the nerve functor $\text{Cat} \rightarrow \text{sSet}$. In light of the fact that the nerve is fully faithful, do quasicategories deserve to be viewed as "the right" extension of category theory? What I mean is: is the point of quasicategories the fact that once their theory is set-up, one can naturally view ordinary categories (even when they are used to investigate quasicategories) as just certain kind of quasicategories?

Continuing with a comment on my question 2., suppose this philosophy is pushed to its limit. One could begin a discussion of quasicategory theory by defining a simplicial set not as a presheaf but as a collection of sets with simplicial operators. Next, one would define $\Delta^n$ and $\Lambda^n_k$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ and simplicial maps as a family of functions commuting with the simplicial operators. Furthermore, one would define a category and a quasicategory as certain kinds of simplicial sets and it would follow immediately that the former is a special case of the latter. Ordinary category theory could then be developed just as it is in classical textbooks (except maybe for set theoretic difficulties). Later when would try to develop the theory of quasicategories, the theory of ordinary categories would quite literally already be a part of it.
I was hoping an expert would comment on all of the above. Thank you very much!

I would say a lot of difficult combinatorial bureaucracies in the formalism of quasicategories can be avoided by using 1-categorical concepts (such as Kan extensions, co/ends, etc) to organize them. So while your second point is logically valid, it would be a hassle to not have the tools of 1-categories when developing the theory of quasicategories.

@Trebor yes, of course, I agree.

It seems to me (but I have not studied the proof in detail) that the theory of quasicategories can be established without first building the homotopy theory of Kan complexes, or at least they can be developed in parallel. This is in contrast to almost every other model, which takes that the homotopy theory of Kan complexes for granted.

Question 1: There are couple of things I can say about this that might be interesting. I do not claim that this is a complete answer to this question.
The model category of complete Segal spaces has nicer properties and is easier understood than the model category of quasicategories. This means that some arguments are easier inside the model of complete Segal spaces, but we must not forget that quasicategories are simpler objects than complete Segal spaces. In a complete Segal space, the structure of composition and the structure of the higher morphisms are separated in two simplicial directions, but since composition (specifically in $(\infty,1)$-categories) can be defined by using higher morphisms, you might suspect that you can encode composition and higher morphisms inside a single simplicial direction, which is precisely what quasicategories achieve. It is easier to work with simplicial sets than bisimplicial sets, which gives quasicategories a certain advantage.
Moreover, the definition of a quasicategory is combinatorial in nature, while the definition of a complete Segal spaces makes reference to weak equivalences in the Kan model structure on simplicial sets, which can be more annoying to work with. You can notice that quasicategories can be studied using more combinatorial techniques in a book like Higher Topos Theory, which is full of combinatorial arguments, and even though you can argue some parts of it can be streamlined, the book still shows the power of being able to use these combinatorial arguments.
Quasicategories are not the only popular model however. The huge amount of work by Joyal, Lurie and others certainly makes it a go-to model, but complete Segal spaces are also often used in particular cases where the $(\infty,1)$-categories people are interested in are more naturally constructed as certain complete Segal spaces, instead of quasicategories. Moreover, if you want to study $(\infty,n)$-categories in general inside some model, changes are large that you pick a Segal-style model. So people interested in, say, $(\infty,2)$-categories may also like complete Segal spaces as model for $(\infty,1)$-categories.
Lastly, a growing amount of people both see the need for model-independent writing styles and feel comfortable with using those. The idea is to write your arguments in such a way that they could be made sense of and proven correct in any "sensible" model for $\infty$-categories. You make sure of course that your argument is correct in one model (usually quasicategories or complete Segal spaces). By using model-independent language, arguments often become clearer, and it also makes (of course) the particular choice of model less important. I would not understimate the amount of mathematicians nowadays that do not deeply care about the model of quasicategories per se, but just want to know that there is some model that proves their intuitive arguments about $\infty$-categories correct, and when writing papers they just choose the model of quasicategories for this reason.
Question 2: The fact that $1$-categories embed fully faithfully into quasicategories is not making them stand out. This holds for any model that I am aware of, and is required to hold in a homotopical sense in order for your model to have the right of calling itself a model for $(\infty,1)$-categories. Indeed, the $(2,1)$-category of (small) $1$-categories is supposed to be a reflective sub-$\infty$-category of the $(\infty,1)$-category of (small) $(\infty,1)$-categories, and this is for all the models I know modelled by a certain fully faithful inclusion of (model) categories.
If we want to be philosophical, we could say that there is no "right" model for $(\infty,1)$-categories. They all model the same $(\infty,1)$-category of $(\infty,1)$-categories after all! There are only models that are more or less convenient for the particular problem you are facing.
